# Expected winning score in a round robin tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Suppose you have a tournament consisting of 100 players in which each player plays each other player exactly once. In any given match, the chance of either playing winning is equally likely, and there are no ties. Winning a match gives $1$ point, and losing a match gives no points.

After all matches have been played, we rank the players according to their score (from highest to lowest), with ties broken at random. For each $n=1,2,\dots, 100$, let $S_n$ be the score of the player ranked $n$ out of $100$.

**Question:** What is the expected value of $S_1$? If it's difficult to find this analytically, how can we approximate the value? The same question holds for other variables, e.g. $S_{10}$, $S_{50}$.

---

Each individual player's score follows a binomial distribution, but these aren't independent: for instance, the total number of points is fixed. One can bound $S_n$ through a bit of combinatorics: e.g., given that there are $4950$ points in total, we must have $S_1 \geq 50$, and we can construct a scenario in which $S_1 = 99$ (which is maximal), so perhaps $S_1 \approx 75$, the midpoint? If I'm looking at $S_{10}$ instead, similar considerations give what I think is $45 \leq S_{10} \leq 94$. But I'm not sure how to evaluate $\mathbb E(S_{10})$ without further considerations.

Comment: You might have a look at John W. Moon's [*Topics on Tournaments*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/42833), particularly Chapter 24, ["The Largest Score in a Tournament](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/42833/42833-pdf.pdf).

Comment: @bof Theorem 34 provides an interval for the highest score centered at $\frac{99} 2 + \sqrt{\frac{99 \ln 99} 2} \approx 64.6$, which is not a bad approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulations reveal that the expected value of the highest score is close to $62$ and that of the lowest score is close to $37$.

Here is the code for a million trials.

```
import numpy as np 

n_players = 100
n_reps = 1000000

res = np.zeros(n_players)
upper_ones = np.ones((n_players,n_players))
upper_ones = np.triu(upper_ones, 1)
summand = np.dot(upper_ones.T, np.ones(n_players))
for _ in range(n_reps):
    sample = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n_players,n_players))
    sample = np.triu(sample)
    scores = summand + np.dot(sample - (sample.T), np.ones(n_players))
    scores_sorted = -np.sort(-scores)
    res += scores_sorted
res = res/n_reps
print(res)
```

The output on my computer was

```
      [61.9787  , 60.205613, 59.207738, 58.490962, 57.922872, 57.446557,
       57.033137, 56.664796, 56.331276, 56.027048, 55.744607, 55.480267,
       55.231936, 54.997983, 54.774691, 54.560586, 54.355605, 54.160058,
       53.971987, 53.788433, 53.608599, 53.434231, 53.264367, 53.103545,
       52.948098, 52.793427, 52.636299, 52.478476, 52.325864, 52.181329,
       52.045519, 51.912301, 51.775257, 51.632466, 51.485957, 51.342442,
       51.208008, 51.083966, 50.965164, 50.84481 , 50.715337, 50.577677,
       50.436025, 50.29887 , 50.172819, 50.057466, 49.947005, 49.831739,
       49.706288, 49.570183, 49.429208, 49.292908, 49.167604, 49.052462,
       48.941925, 48.826662, 48.700781, 48.564489, 48.422693, 48.28377 ,
       48.154248, 48.033372, 47.915259, 47.790658, 47.656015, 47.512366,
       47.365977, 47.223311, 47.086521, 46.953544, 46.817191, 46.673013,
       46.521177, 46.364323, 46.207313, 46.051975, 45.895711, 45.734553,
       45.565879, 45.39038 , 45.210333, 45.027164, 44.839621, 44.644297,
       44.43911 , 44.225171, 44.00205 , 43.767837, 43.51958 , 43.256553,
       42.974049, 42.66924 , 42.337103, 41.96929 , 41.555295, 41.079778,
       40.510671, 39.793988, 38.797513, 37.027683]
```

Here is a plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get a good approximation by making the correct assumption that each player's score is a binomial distribution with parameters $99$ and $\frac12$ and the slightly wrong assumption that each player's total score is independent of the other players.

You could use the distributions for order statistics for $100$ independent samples from this distribution, using the beta and binomial distributions.  Using R for a form of numerical integration:

- For $S_1$ `mean(qbinom(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),100,1),99,1/2))` gives about $61.91$ compared to Gabriel Romon's simulation of $61.98$
- For $S_{10}$ `mean(qbinom(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),91,10),99,1/2))` gives about $55.99$ compared to Gabriel Romon's simulation of $56.03$
- For $S_{50}$ `mean(qbinom(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),51,50),99,1/2))` gives about $49.56$ compared to Gabriel Romon's simulation of $49.57$

The simulation has a small amount of noise while the approximation makes a false assumption which affects the results, but they are broadly similar.

Answer (score -2):

99 is a pretty big number, we can use normal distribution. Average is 49.5, Standard-deviation is $\frac{\sqrt{99}}{2}=4.975$ ; Excel gives the result :

loi.normale(56; 49.5;4.975;True)=0.90

90% of scores are lower than 56.

Comment: If you take this approach, you should probably use a continuity correction.  In fact about $88.6\%$ are lower than $56$ and about $92.0\%$ are $56$ or lower,  But that is for an individual player, while this question is about order statistics

Comment: With 100 people, you could use this to estimate that $S_{10}$ should be about 56, which is about right.  To get $S_1$, you'd want `...=0.99`, I believe.  But you'd need to carefully consider what assumptions you're making.